# JSON to C# Converter and display in DatagridViewer

Tags: json, datagrid

Can anyone please suggest me with a script to convert any dynamic JSON script to display the values with column heads in DataGridViewer?

I am using C# code and need in a WindowsForm to install it as a client tool.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, try this tool online:

> http://json2csharp.com/

there are more

Comment: I do not want to copy the Client Data over there...So Want to build up a C# small app which can handle this piece.